# Paypal 406 not acceptable Not Acceptable address error

Tags: soap, paypal, paypal-sandbox, http-status-code-406

When we try to place and order through **PaypalExpressCheckout**, We are unable to connect to paypal, We see the below exception

```
[5/15/23 16:27:29:039 GMT] 00000109 SOAPOverHTTPS E   WSWS7263E: The following exception occured: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: HTTP ( 406 ) Not Acceptable address : https://api.paypal.com/2.0/
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.processStatusCode(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:3763)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.send(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:635)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPTransportSender.invoke(HTTPTransportSender.java:386)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:556)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:578)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:127)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:419)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy151.setExpressCheckout(Unknown Source)
    at com.hp.payment.paypal.commands.PayPalSetExpressCheckoutCmdImpl.performExecute(PayPalSetExpressCheckoutCmdImpl.java:633)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.ECCommandTarget.executeCommand(ECCommandTarget.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.command.CommandCache.executeCommand(CommandCache.java:332)
    at com.ibm.websphere.command.CacheableCommandImpl.execute(CacheableCommandImpl.java:167)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.MeasuredCacheableCommandImpl.execute(MeasuredCacheableCommandImpl.java:69)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.AbstractECTargetableCommand.execute(AbstractECTargetableCommand.java:200)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.BaseComponentImpl.executeCommand(BaseComponentImpl.java:285)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.WebAdapterComponentImpl.executeCommand(WebAdapterComponentImpl.java:46)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.objimpl.WebAdapterServiceBeanBase.executeCommand(WebAdapterServiceBeanBase.java:43)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.objects.EJSLocalNSLWebAdapterService_bd9a6c99.executeCommand(EJSLocalNSLWebAdapterService_bd9a6c99.java)
    at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.WebControllerHelper.executeCommand(WebControllerHelper.java:2779)
    at com.ibm.commerce.struts.v2.AjaxAction.invokeService(AjaxAction.java:637)
    at com.ibm.commerce.struts.v2.AjaxAction.executeAction(AjaxAction.java:449)
    at com.ibm.commerce.struts.v2.AjaxAction.execute(AjaxAction.java:249)
    at com.ibm.commerce.struts.v2.AjaxAction.execute(AjaxAction.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1357.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:899)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1544)
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:90)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1620)
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:470)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:434)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:492)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:544)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:490)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:293)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    at com.ibm.commerce.struts.v2.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor.intercept(CacheHeadersInterceptor.java:48)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:250)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:49)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.doIntercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:142)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:140)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:140)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:201)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:67)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:101)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:142)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:160)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:175)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:121)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:196)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:48)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:79)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:141)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.server.services.servlet.filter.HttpSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpSecurityFilter.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.filter.CacheFilter$1.run(CacheFilter.java:393)
    at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:556)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.hp.ecom.b2c.service.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:134)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.doFilterAction(RuntimeServletFilter.java:839)
    at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.access$0(RuntimeServletFilter.java:618)
    at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter$1.run(RuntimeServletFilter.java:462)
    at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.doFilter(RuntimeServletFilter.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.hp.filter.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:37)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.hp.seo.filter.SEOSecurityCheckFilter.doFilter(SEOSecurityCheckFilter.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.hp.seo.filter.SEOPdpCLPRedirectFilter.doFilter(SEOPdpCLPRedirectFilter.java:407)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.hp.seo.filter.SEOHPCoBrandDynamicToStaticFilter.doFilter(SEOHPCoBrandDynamicToStaticFilter.java:185)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.hp.seo.filter.SEOContentViewRedirectFilter.doFilter(SEOContentViewRedirectFilter.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.hp.seo.filter.SEOCaseConversionFilter.doFilter(SEOCaseConversionFilter.java:346)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.hp.vanity.filter.SEOVanityURLFilter.doFilter(SEOVanityURLFilter.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1119)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4238)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2210)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1033)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
 
The previous error might have been caused by a lack of system resources due to server is too busy processing multiple requests.
[5/15/23 16:27:29:042 GMT] 00000109 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /opt/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/default/logs/container/ts_wcsuat3livets-app-5f4c7b799b-fq5nb/ffdc/server1_baad03e3_23.05.15_16.27.29.0403917712438167488214.txt com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPTransportSender.invoke 410
```

This happens only when we connect to "**[https://api.paypal.com/2.0/**"](https://api.paypal.com/2.0/**%22) but when we point it to "**[https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/**"](https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/**%22) it works fine. We tried checking the certificate and it looks good. Tried checking the headers and it seems to be good.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: If an HTTPS channel with `https://api.paypal.com/2.0/` is being opened, then for debugging verbosely log the connection (similar to `curl -v https://api.paypal.com/2.0/`, but preferably from your code/app itself with your certificate file and other credentials as part of the request) and add that log here to your question, importantly including the request headers among other details.  xxxxxxx out any details of the transmission that shouldn't be posted here

Comment: Thanks @Preston . We found out the issue. It was due to an expired paypal  certificate